# TextView not passing control to its ListItem (Expandable list -> Group View)

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview

I am using expandable list in that under the getGroupView() method I am following layout.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:background="@drawable/groupheaderbg" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/groupimgview"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:contentDescription="@string/groupImageViewDesc"
     android:padding="@dimen/TENDP"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/lblheader"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/childgroupimgview"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:text="@string/groupImageViewDesc"
     android:textIsSelectable="true"
     android:textSize="18sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:focusable="false"

     android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     android:clickable="false"
      />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Expandable list not expanding and collapse due to textview as textview not passing click event to expandable list item.
I tried following approach, so now textview selection menu is not appearing but the problem remain the same(not passing control to list item).

```
         android:focusable="false"

         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:clickable="false"
          />
```

Apart from it I have tried following trough code as well.

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(null);
                tv.setFocusable(false);
                tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);



                tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                      @Override
                      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // return TRUE since we want to consume the event
                        return false; 
                      }
                    });
```

do I need to intercept touch event? if yes then Please advise / suggest for the same.

or is there any way in which we can instruct textview to handover touch event / click event to it parent view.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied onclickListener to textview and controlling expanding and collapsing from there programmatically.

Incase if someone found better approach to do this, please share. :)